# CSS3 ONLY get element's index for calculation

Tags: html, css

I'm reading through [this CSS3 reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) and can't find the magic selector I am hoping for. What I want to do is get the variable 'n' in an nth-child selector to use in calc(). So for example, say I had

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

In CSS3 only, I would really like to do something like:

```
li:nth-child(n) {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  width: calc(100px * n)   -- Where n references the elements index
}
```

This should yield a stairs looking shape, because the width of each successive element would be larger.

But this obviously doesn't work the way I have coded it. Is there some way to do this in pure CSS3?

I can most certainly do this in Javascript, but I want to write as little javascript as possible.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw66D/)

Comment: I'm not aware of CSS3 having the ability to reference the index in the :nth pseudo classes.

Comment: @j08691 good call, I didn't notice that one in the related questions.